# Get parsed/interpolated value for angular directive in compile or template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quite a few of our directives are dynamic in the sense that the output html can be determined by a variable. For example

```
<div ng-repeat="m in arry">
    <my-directive options="m.options"></my-directive>
</div>
```

And then `myDirective` can change its output html based on, for example, `m.options.template`

Currently we are just using a giant `ng-switch` for handling this,

```
<div ng-switch="options.template">
    <div ng-switch-when="richText"></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="select"></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="number"></div>
</div>
```

but started to notice performance issues.

A better approach I think would be to insert the html based on the `m.options.template` from `my-directive` itself. I would like to do this at the `compile` stage for performance reasons, but I do not have access to the scope and so cannot determine the value of `m.options.template` before the link.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Why not just use ngInclude?

Comment: You have to have scope, since this is how you know what template to use.